# How to make TypeScript type inferencing work for arrays

Tags: typescript

I have a type/interface for a collection of properties.
Each property has its own type specified. See `Props` in the code example below.

I'm trying to define a type that is a tuple `<A, B>`, where `A` must be the name of one of the properties and `B` must be of the corresponding type of the value of that property.

For example, `['someStr', 'a']` should satisfy the type, while `['someStr', 1]` should fail since according to `Props` `1` must be a string.

Here's some experimenting code:

```
interface Props { 
    someStr: string;
    someNum: number;
}

type FuncWithPropInput = <T extends keyof Props>(key: T, value: Props[T]) => [typeof key, typeof value];

// I don't have to specify `T` as it's inferred from `key`.
const workWithProps: FuncWithPropInput = (key, value) => [key, value];

workWithProps('someStr', 'a'); // No error, as expected.
workWithProps('someStr', 5); // Error about `5` not a string, as expected.
workWithProps('foobar', 5); // Error about `'foobar'` not in collection, as expected.

type TupleWithPropKeyAndValue<T extends keyof Props> = [
    T,
    Props[T]
];

// Unexpected: it complains about missing type argument `T`.
const var1: TupleWithPropKeyAndValue = [
    'someStr',
    5 // Unexpected: No error here.
];

const var2: TupleWithPropKeyAndValue<'someStr'> = [
    'someStr',
    5 // Error about `5` not a string, as expected.
];

const var3: ReturnType<FuncWithPropInput> = [
    'someStr',
    5 // Unexpected: No error here.
];
```

The confusion I have is that `FuncWithPropInput` in the example above works, but the `TupleWithPropKeyAndValue` doesn't work.

I want to be able to write something like the case of `var1` and have TypeScript throw an error about `5` must be a string.

Moreover, since `FuncWithPropInput` works as expected, I'm baffled to see the case of `var3` failing.

Comment: How does `['someStr', 'a']` satifies your needs if the second element needs to be a type? (`'a'` isn't a type, no?)

Comment: @KevinPastor `'a'` satisfies because `Props['someStr'] === string` and `'a'` is a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type inference for variables is an all or nothing affair. Either the type is inferred based on the initialization expression or the type is set by the type annotation and no inference occurs. There is no partial inference like you expect for `var1` where you specify the generic type and Typescript fills in the blanks.

The usual way to get around this is the one you already found. Use a function to infer a type parameter that is constrained in some way.

The  reason `ReturnType`doesn't do what you expect is that Typescript will just use the widest possible type for the type parameter and return the return type for that no other magic will happen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it reasonable for me to believe that, technically, TypeScript could totally do the inferencing for array initialization (like it does for function calls), but it just decides to not do that for whatever reason?

Comment: @Tingo I guess it could do it.. But using a function should not be that big a problem and my guess is that nobody bothered implementing it like this also the syntax might need to be as complicated as it would be for function type parameters. So probably not worth it.